# Scraping JSON data from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP function that echoes out JSON data and pagination links. The data looks exactly like this.

```
[{"name":"John Doe","favourite":"cupcakes"},{"name":"Jane Citizen","favourite":"Baked beans"}]
Previous
Next
```

To get these data, I would use jQuery.ajax() function. My code are as follow:-

```
function loadData(page){                
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://sandbox.dev/favourite/test",
        data: "page="+page,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#area").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                $("#area").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Using jQuery, is there anyway I can scrape the data returned from the AJAX request and use the JSON data? Or is there a better way of doing this? I'm just experimenting and would like to paginate JSON data.

Comment: Why do you use `ajaxComplete` within the success handler? Remove it, and fill `#area` directly.

Comment: You don't need the `ajaxComplete` function - as your are already in the `success` callback function you can just put the plain `$("#area").html(msg);` in there.

Comment: You can use `.split()` or `.substr()` with `.indexOf()` or a regex method to take everything up to the first carriage return and then parse it as JSON, but why does your PHP return the format shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to not invent your own formats (like adding HTML links after JSON) for such things. JSON is already capable of holding any structure you need. For example you may use the following form:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"name": "John Doe", "favourite": "cupcakes"},
        {"name": "Jane Citizen", "favourite": "Baked beans"}
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "prev": "previous page URL",
        "next": "next page URL"
    }
}
```

On client-side it can be parsed very easily:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(resp) { 
        // use resp.data and resp.pagination here
    }
});
```

Comment: This is much cleaner! I rewrote my PHP to include pagination values as part of the JSON response. I wish I could upvote this but I do not have enough rep. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Don't forget to get back with upvote when available ;)

Answer (score 1):

put a **dataType** to your ajax request to receive a **json object** or you will receive a string.

if you put "previous" and "next" in your json..that will be invalid.

```
function loadData(page){                
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://sandbox.dev/favourite/test",
        data: {'page':page},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(msg){ 
            if(typeof (msg) == 'object'){
              // do something... 
            }else{
              alert('invalid json');
            }
        },
        complete:function(){ 
           //do something
        }
    });
}
```

and .. in your php file, put a header

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
// print your json..
```

To see your json object... use console.log , like this:

```
// your ajax....
success:(msg){
if( window.console ) console.dir( typeof(msg), msg);
}
```

Change your json to something like this: (Use jsonlint to validate it - http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "paginate": {
        "previous": "http...previsouslink",
        "next": "http...nextlink"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "JohnDoe",
            "favourite": "cupcakes"
        },
        {
            "name": "JaneCitizen",
            "favourite": "Bakedbeans"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yeap @Christoph! that's why i put "**if you put "previous" and "next" in your json..that will be invalid.**". you can check your json, when returns... if(typeof (msg) == 'object'){ }else{alert('invalid json');}.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scraping the JSON data i'd suggest you to return pure JSON data.  As per your use case I don't think its necessary to write the `Previous` and `Next`.  I am guessing that the first object in your return url is for `Previous` and the next one is for `Next`.  Simply return the below string...

```
[{"name":"John Doe","favourite":"cupcakes"},{"name":"Jane Citizen","favourite":"Baked beans"}]
```

and read it as under.

```
function loadData(page){                
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://sandbox.dev/favourite/test",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(msg)
        {
            var previous = msg[0];  //This will give u your previous object and
            var next = msg[1]; //this will give you your next object

            //You can use prev and next here.

            //$("#area").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            //{
            //    $("#area").html(msg);
            //});
        }
    });
}
```

*This way return only that data that's going to change not the entire html.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
var jsObject = JSON.parse(your_data);

data = JSON.parse(gvalues);
var result = data.key;
var result1 = data.values[0];
```